# Spring Boot Annotation @Autowired of Service fails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-boot

I'm trying to use `@Autowired` annotation for a Service class in Spring Boot application, but it keeps throwing `No qualifying bean of type` exception. However, if I change the service class to a bean, then it works fine. This is my code:

```
package com.mypkg.domain;
@Service
public class GlobalPropertiesLoader {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService sampleService;        
}

package com.mypkg.service;
@Service
public class SampleService{

}
```

And this is my SpringBoot class:

```
package com.mypkg;

import java.util.Set;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TrackingService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrackingService.class);

    static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TrackingService.class, args);
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.refresh();
        context.close();

    }

}
```

When I try to run this, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mypkg.service.SampleService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

But when I remove the `@Service` annotation from the SampleService class, and add it as a bean in my AppConfig class as below, it works fine:

```
@Configuration
public class AppServiceConfig {

    public AppServiceConfig() {
    }

    @Bean(name="sampleService")
    public SampleService sampleService(){
        return new SampleService();
    }

}
```

The classes are in different packages. I am not using `@ComponentScan`. Instead, I'm using `@SpringBootApplication` which does that automatically. However, I tried with ComponentScan as well but that didn't help.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show your `Application` class (the one with the `main` method)?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code for the main class.

Comment: @drunkenfist Why are you closing the context? You know it will destroy all the beans rite.

Comment: @drunkenfist I couldn't reproduce this issue at first, with pretty much the same code you posted. Then at some stage I realized when I added the `@Service` annotation and hit the quick import, I got two choices. So there was a _second_ `@Service` coming from some dependency I had in my pom, in this case `spring-boot-starter-jersey` but there could be others. It sounds like a long shot, but could you check the exact import for your `@Service`?

Comment: I've typed in a similar example and it all works perfectly. As stated above can you check the fully qualified package name of the @Service annotation you are imported ?

Comment: You should accept @EdduMelendez's answer as it solves your issue and explains in detail why you should do it the way he suggested.

Answer (score 18):

You are using two ways to build a Spring's bean. You just need to use one of them.

1. `@Service` over the POJO

   ```
    @Service
    public class SampleService
   ```
2. `@Bean` in the configuration class which must be annotated with `@Configuration`

   ```
    @Bean
    public SampleService sampleService(){
        return new SampleService();
    }
   ```

`@Autowired` is resolved by class type then `@Bean(name="sampleService")` is not needed is you have only one bean with that class type.

**EDIT 01**

package com.example

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("repo " + userRepository);
        System.out.println("serv " + userService);
    }
}
```

package com.example.config

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserRepository userRepository() {
        System.out.println("repo from bean");
        return new UserRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserService userService() {
        System.out.println("ser from bean");
        return new UserService();
    }
}
```

package com.example.repository

```
@Service
public class UserRepository {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("repo from @service");
    }
}
```

package com.example.service

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("service from @service");
    }

}
```

Using this code you can comment the `AppConfig` class and then you will see how `UserRepository` and `UserService` are autowired. After that comment `@Service` in each class and un-comment `AppConfig` and classes will be autowired too.

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. I'm using only one of the methods. When I annotate it with `@Service` over the POJO, it fails. But when I use `@Bean` in my configuration class, it works. I want to know why the `@Service` way fails.

Comment: I have updated the answer. static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context; is used? spring boot manage the lifecycle so not sure why you are using context.refresh() and context.close()

Comment: For me the `@Service` method is not working. It is only fetching if it is declared as a `@Bean`.

Comment: I am using spring-boot 1.2.3.RELEASE. Which version are you using? Are you using my example or a mix of both?

Comment: I have the same issue, I am using spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE. It works when I use @Bean(name="sampleService") but does not work when I use only @Bean